# How can i share a wirecloud marketplace between users

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I built some widgets and uploaded on my local marketplace, is there a way to share that?

And better is it possible to share a Mashup (the widget composition) without giving the
possibility to wiring to the user?

I mean the user should use an application layout without change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can make public your workspaces/dashboards following the steps documented in the [user guide](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Application_Mashup_-_Wirecloud_-_User_and_Programmer_Guide#Sharing_your_mashups). Only the owner of a workspace will be able to modify it. I think this is what are you searching for.

Another option is to create a packaged mashup using the "Upload to my resources" option in the editor view:

[image]

Take a look to the "Advanced" tab, where you can block widgets (make them unremovable), block connections (make wiring connections unremovable) and embed used widgets/operator (by default packaged mashups depends on the user having installed all the required widgets/operators. This way you can distribute the widgets and operators used by the mashup in the same package).

However, take into account that this method is meant for sharing mashup templates, the user will always be able to add additional widgets and create new connections in the wiring view.

Once packaged, mashups/dashboards (and widgets and operators) can be uploaded to a WStore server (e.g. to the Store portal provided on FIWARE Lab) for sharing them with other users. The steps for making this is also described in the [WireCloud's user guide](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Application_Mashup_-_Wirecloud_-_User_and_Programmer_Guide#Publishing_mashable_application_components_into_Stores).

Comment: at the moment [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882945/wirecloud-and-idm-integration-internal-server-error-during-login) prevents me to go on testing if your solution is ok

Comment: I cannot find "Upload to my resources", into Editor view, but under "workspace"  there is "**Upload to local catalogue**" that seems to have an "Advance tab", is that what you mean? BTW The dialog are not very usable... i will open a new question for that or bug on github if you prefer

Comment: Once i uploaded to local catalogue, do i need to upload it also to WStore to make it available to other users, or i have to add a new marketplace pointing to a local one?

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem, revisited.
I have set up a working Marketplace instance (v2.3) but am unable to integrate it with Wirecloud. The marketplace is correctly registered but all the requests i am making to this Marketplace are throwing 502 error, even though i am actually able to see some results when querying the Marketplace server through a browser.

Indicatively, i can issue a GET command at http://:8080/FiwareMarketplace/v1/registration/stores/ and get an answer, but Wirecloud's internal APIs return a 502 (Bad Gateway).

Any idea on what might have gone wrong?

PS: This happens for WC v0.6.5. When upgrading to a newer (Beta) version of WC, everything seems to be performing as expected, i.e. the marketplace is correctly inserted and the stores are correctly retrieved and processed.