# WireCloud and IDM integration internal server error during login

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I'm trying to add to the [FITMAN](http://www.fitman-fi.eu/) Trial 5 structure, the [IDM GE](https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-idm) to have a SSO.

I followed the WireCloud installation guide [here](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Application_Mashup_-_Wirecloud_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Integration_with_the_IdM_GE).

To test that integration I used two virtual box machines configured to be into a host-only LAN:

- IDM => 192.168.56.6:3000
- WC  => 192.168.56.4:8080

I created (sign up) a user using IDM and got some [problems](https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-idm/issues/71) but worked it around by using the right local link, and an application for the id and secret code. This is the screenshot of the IdM configuration:

[image: IdM configuration]

This is the error response:

[image]

And this is the log from WireCloud:

```
[12/Nov/2014 02:32:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1393 
[12/Nov/2014 02:32:54] "GET /static/cache/css/0d24b047d2b9.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 
[12/Nov/2014 02:32:54] "GET /static/cache/js/710ae45ffdc1.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 
[12/Nov/2014 02:32:54] "GET /api/context HTTP/1.1" 200 538
[12/Nov/2014 02:32:54] "GET /api/preferences/platform HTTP/1.1" 200 2 
[12/Nov/2014 02:32:54] "GET /static/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.woff?0505fc36f188 HTTP/1.1" 304 0 
[12/Nov/2014 02:32:54] "GET /static/fonts/comfortaa_bold-webfont.woff?0505fc36f188 HTTP/1.1" 304 0 
[12/Nov/2014 02:32:54] "GET /api/workspaces HTTP/1.1" 200 2 
[12/Nov/2014 02:32:54] "GET /static/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.woff?0505fc36f188 HTTP/1.1" 304 0 
[12/Nov/2014 02:32:54] "GET /static/fonts/comfortaa_bold-webfont.woff?0505fc36f188 HTTP/1.1" 304 0 
[12/Nov/2014 02:32:54] "GET /static/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1&0505fc36f188 HTTP/1.1" 304 0 
[12/Nov/2014 02:32:56] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 0 
[12/Nov/2014 02:32:56] "GET /login/fiware/?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 0 
[12/Nov/2014 02:33:09] "GET /complete/fiware/?code=Qc60v4BAYrcxGksyziJlMpVBRoeJG92wCURPkAxinaVmWY0EnzOIUe_G--WOkXHuSwE3AbAZfYfEItjXxMuBGA HTTP/1.1" 500 479 
[12/Nov/2014 02:33:09] "GET /static/cache/css/80dc877aa113.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 
[12/Nov/2014 02:33:48] "GET /complete/fiware/?code=Qc60v4BAYrcxGksyziJlMpVBRoeJG92wCURPkAxinaVmWY0EnzOIUe_G--WOkXHuSwE3AbAZfYfEItjXxMuBGA HTTP/1.1" 500 480
```

Comment: using a rest client the response was: 

    Status Code: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
    Content-Encoding: gzip
    Content-Language: en
    Content-Length: 480
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Date: Wed, 12 Nov 2014 08:33:48 GMT
    Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.6.6
    Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie, Accept-Encoding

Comment: Please, edit your settings.py file and set DEBUG to True for getting more info about the error.

Comment: indeed i have it already:
DEBUG = True

Comment: I am probably wrong in configuring Application, can you please point me on the right way of configuring Call back and URL in IDM for wirecloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a problem with the Callback URL field of the IdM Configuration. It should be: `http://192.168.56.4:8080/complete/fiware/`

Comment: I also had to add **social-auth** into INSTALLED_APPS and run the command
**python manage.py syncdb --migrate**